# beautifulsoup4 html.parser returns "'module' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble doing the first steps of creating a web **scraper**. When I try to convert my text file into a soup object
soup= beautifulsoup(html.text, "html.parser")

I get --> type error:'module' object is not callable

However, I can run the code within a completely different notebook from my GA class, it seems to be the only notebook I can run the parser.  I tried uninstalling the beautifulsoup library.  I updated my pip to pip3 and then updated to beautifulsoup4, to match my version of python, and I am still having the same problem.  [,f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb85h.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try importing like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

run:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
```

That should solve your problem, good luck!